# Should I play Gears of War 3 directly instead of going through 1 and 2?

Tags: gears-of-war-3

I haven't played Gears of War 1 or 2. Because of the great marketing hype created for Gears 3, I was thinking of buying one. How will my gaming experience be if I directly jump on to Gears 3?

Comment: I would guess that it's designed to be played and enjoyed by someone who hasn't played the previous two, but there might be subtleties that are only apparent if you have.

Comment: http://penny-arcade.com/comic/2011/09/21

Comment: @Hackworth So GoW has no story? Find it a little hard to believe after watching the "Brothers till the end" melodrama! :)

Comment: I am not taking even a passing interest in the Gears series, I barely heard of it. From what I *have* heard, though, Gears doesn't sound like the game you play for the story... But hey, don't take it from me: http://www.vgcats.com/comics/?strip_id=288

Comment: In case you decide to go looking for information using those acronyms, the "Gears of War" series is typically shortened to "Gears", not "GoW", to avoid confusion with the God of War series.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you only play multiplayer, then you aren't missing anything by skipping Gears 1 or 2 (other than familiarity with the game mechanics).

As for the single player, there is a story and it does tie up a lot of loose ends from the first two games (I haven't played much of the campaign yet, this is just what I've heard from reviews and such). There is a "previously on Gears" intro movie that you can play before the campaign starts to get you up to speed.

If you watch the intro movie, and possibly read about the plot of the first two games on the internet, you would probably have enough info to not be confused by the story in Gears 3.

Comment: That helps, thanks. Will give GoW 3 a try! :)

Comment: I don't know, that 'welcome to' story was pretty sparse. But the Gears 3 story is definitely a step down from Gears 2, and even having played both (albeit a while ago) I was still lost at times, so I'll give you +1.