# Should I catch up with the Gears of War series or just start with part 3?

Tags: gears-of-war-3, gears-of-war, gears-of-war-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I play GOW3 directly instead of going through GOW1 & 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30825/should-i-play-gow3-directly-instead-of-going-through-gow1-2)

Like many gamers, I often purchase games and then do not have time to play through them. I now own all 3 Gears of War games and have only played through part of the first one. Is this a series that would be more enjoyable to start from the beginning or should I just play the latest and greatest in the series first?

I do not plan on playing much online so the newness of the game isn't a concern for me in that regard. I am more curious about the story line and getting the maximum enjoyment out of the series.

Comment: See http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30825/should-i-play-gow3-directly-instead-of-going-through-gow1-2

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in the story, I'd highly suggest actually playing through the campaigns. The developers at Epic Games did a effective job at building a compelling setting, backstory, and narrative. Reading the plot summaries won't do it justice.

Comment: It might be worth adding this answer to the original question because it provides an alternate viewpoint to the answer there.